# Calling a function in another process using JNA

Tags: java, winapi, jna

I am writing a Java program using JNA that should attach itself to another process and invoke functions at various addresses within that process memory space.

I have set JNA as a dependency as well as the platform contrib that is part of the JNA project, however I notice that within the Kernel32 class there is no mapping to `VirtualAllocEx`, `WriteProcessMemory`, and some others. I believe that those functions are needed for this task, but perhaps there is a better way or maybe they have been implemented somewhere else.

Is there a way to do it using the win32 platform contrib? If so where should I look? If not are there any other options, or will I have to map those functions from Kernel32 on my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend an existing library mapping, simply extend the interface and generate a new instance:

```
public interface MyLibrary extends OriginalLibrary {
    MyLibrary INSTANCE = (MyLibrary)Native.loadLibrary("name"[, options]);
    void extensionFunction();
}
```

You now have a library mapping that includes all the original stuff, plus your methods.  Take note that when extending a w32 API mapping you should pass in the same options (usually `W32API_DEFAULT_OPTIONS`); see the corresponding library mapping's call to `Native.loadLibrary()` for details.